# Loading custom control library resource dictionary or styles implicitly in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, themes, custom-controls, resourcedictionary

I am working on one WPF Custom Control Library exposing styles like **Generic**, **Aero2** etc. inside Themes folder. I have also set my assembly ThemeInfo to refer to my SourceAssembly.

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly, 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly 
)]
```

But the styles are only applied when i am merging the ResourceDictionary below in App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyWPFCustomControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyWPFCustomControl;component/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Question: How can i implicitly load theme based styles without explicitly merging resource dictionary as in above statement?